# Install TensorFlow 2.2 using Conda on macOS

Tags: macos, tensorflow, installation, conda

Just checking if anyone knows whether Anaconda Project has released TensorFlow 2.2 and above for macOS users? From my understanding, this version of TF exists for all platforms except Mac.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the option to check things like this on the anaconda website. Just go to https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow and you will see:

```
linux-64  v2.2.0
win-64  v2.1.0
osx-64  v2.0.0
```

so the newest version available for macOS from the `anaconda` channel is (currently) 2.0.0

Alternatively you can also always run

```
conda search tensorflow
```

to see which versions are available for your platform

**Note**

> From my understanding, this version of TF exists for all platforms except Mac

From anaconda, yes, but you are definately able to find this version on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0/#files), i.e. use pip install to install it

Comment: Thanks. This is so frustrant. Cannot understand why TF version on conda is so old.

Comment: `conda-forge` has 2.6.2 for both osx-x64 and arm